# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append' on line 9?

Tags: list, split, append

Q.)8.4 Open the file romeo.txt and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.
**this code is giving AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append' on line 9**

```
    fname = input("Enter file name: ")
        fh = open(fname)
        lst = {}
        for line in fh:
            line = line.rstrip()
            words = line.split()
            for word in words:
                if word not in lst:
                    lst.append(word)
        print(sorted(lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionary has no `append` method.

Append is used in the list (array) in Python. Make `lst` a list, not a dictionary. I have made a minor change in your code below, changing

```
lst = {}   #creation of an empty dictionary
```

to

```
lst = []    #creation of an empty list
```

The full code:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
        fh = open(fname)
        lst = []
        for line in fh:
            line = line.rstrip()
            words = line.split()
            for word in words:
                if word not in lst:
                    lst.append(word)
        print(sorted(lst))
```

Comment: Before upvoting I made a significant edit to your answer, in order to hilight the difference between empty list/dictionary creation. If you think it is too _invasive_ feel free to revert it.